# С++ Форматирование текста в тг боте / tgbot/tgbot.h

Tags: telegram, visual-c++

Пытаюсь сделать вывод текста ботом жирным форматом, не получается, хоть на сайте Api написано делать через text.
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <tgbot/tgbot.h>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

using namespace TgBot;
using namespace std;

vector<string>bot_commands = { "start", "time", "proizvod", "integral" };

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");

    bot_main.getEvents().onCommand("start", [&bot_main](Message::Ptr message)
        {
            bot_main.getApi().sendMessage(message->chat->id, "**hi, **" + message->chat->firstName + "\n/help -" + " / proizvod - command for picture proizvod.\n" +
            "/integral - command for picture integralov");

            int64_t chatId = message->chat->id;
            string text = "<b>Привет!</b>\nЭто жирное сообщение!";

            bot_main.getApi().sendMessage(chatId, text, "HTML");
            
        });

     try 
 {
     printf("Bot username: %s\n", bot_main.getApi().getMe()->username.c_str());
     TgLongPoll longPoll(bot_main);
     while (true) {
         printf("Long poll started\n");
         longPoll.start();
     }
 }
 catch (TgException& e) 
 {
     printf("error: %s\n", e.what());
 }

 

 return 0;

}
```

p.s. вставлена только часть кода, по сути урезал то что не должно просто мешать